# Display three reusbale cells in tableview - Swift 5

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview, cell

I have 3 UITableViewCell with XIB files but on my tableview I can't display my three UITableViewCell, only can load the first two

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (indexPath.item % 2 == 0) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CaptureNameTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CaptureNameTableViewCell
        cell.nameTextField.text = ""
        cell.nameTextField.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.nameTextField.delegate = self
        return cell
    } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CapturePhotoTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CapturePhotoTableViewCell
        cell.displayImage = imageView
        cell.cellDelegate = self
        cell.selectImage.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PieChartTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PieChartTableViewCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the xib tableViewCells inside of the tableViewController:

First create an `id` property inside of the cells xib class, to use as the cell’s reuse identifier (make the name of this the same as your reuse identifier for the cell which you set in the xib file):

```
let id = "cellIdentifier" // Name this appropriately
```

Then create a `nib` method inside of the cell's xib class:

```
func nib() -> UINib {
    return UINib(named: "cellIdentifier", bundle: nil)
}
```

Then inside of a lifecycle method such as `viewDidLoad()`:

```
tableView.register(nib: cell.nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: cell.id)
```

Finally, specify which cells you want to be where in the table view at which indexPath.row. (Which row in the table view):

```
switch indexPath.row {
    case 0: // First cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CaptureNameTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CaptureNameTableViewCell
        // Configure cell as before
        return cell
    case 1: // Second cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CapturePhotoTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CapturePhotoTableViewCell
        // Configure cell as before
        return cell
    case 2: // Third cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PieChartTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PieChartTableViewCell
        // Configure cell as before
        return cell
    default:
        return UITableViewCell() // This should not be reached but a switch statement must cover all possibilities.
}
```

Comment: I already did it that way and I only present the first XIB with ID CaptureNameTableViewCell but, the other 2 XIBs are not presented in the table ...

Comment: I have updated my answer hopefully, that works how you're expecting now. I don't think you were inserting the cells into their rows correctly currently.